# How to make button show content onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to make it show the div when i click the button, what am i doing wrong?

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<div class="dglow">Glow</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        dglow.style.display='block'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors? Cant see anything jumping out at me.

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
 document.getElementById("Dglow")
```

but your element has not an id but a class.

You have 2 ways to fix it:

1) Add an id to your element

```
<div id="Dglow" class="Dglow">
    Glow
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8s9v6es/1/)

2) Call find the element with the class

```
function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName('Dglow');
    y[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8s9v6es/)

Hope it may helps you.

Comment: Thanks :)
But i wanted to add a new button that hides it, shouldn't it be the same?
I have no clue why it's not working.

<script>

function myFunctionHide() {
document.getElementById("Dglow").style.display="none";
}

</script>

Answer (score 0):

You have confused class with id.

You say :

```
class = "Dglow"
```

But in javascript you did:

```
getElementById("Dglow")
```

Instead make the html equal to:

```
id = "Dglow"
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add id in your div.

```js
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("Dglow").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.Dglow
{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<div id="Dglow" class="Dglow">
Glow
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you want ?
Changed class to Id and it shows and hides.

```js
var dglow=document.getElementById("dglow");

function myFunction(){
    var style=dglow.style.display;
        if(style=='block')
         {
            dglow.style.display='none';
         }
     else{
            dglow.style.display='block';
         }       
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<div id="dglow" style="display:none;">Glow</div>
```